# Custom Tables in Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, session, crud, camunda

I have a Spring Boot Application. Camunda tables are in a Postgresql database. Now I want to create my own entities and create custom tables in the same database.
Table creation is done, I can read (Get) data from it, however, I can’t write into it. Post, Put and delete methods always return the following error :
“java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed”
I was wondering if this issue is related to some specific rules or rights, especially that I tried the same CRUD methods on another postgresql database (without camunda) and they worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not related to Camunda permissions. How did you create the service, Spring Data? It is a REST service?

Comment: @rob2universe, yes it's REST. I just created my entity, the table is created, Get methods work fine but Post methods always return that session error

Comment: How did you create the service? Can you share more info about your deployment and config?

Comment: I followed this tutorial to create my entity : https://www.javaguides.net/2019/01/springboot-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-restful-api-tutorial.html .. the only difference is that app.yaml says that "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" is unknown.. other than that I tried this example on a different db without camunda and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any other hibernate dialect defined. Maybe a H2Dialect leftover from the standard camunda config?

See if setting

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the path to my api got caught in the registerFilter. I just needed to change the path. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://forum.camunda.org/t/startprocessinstancebykey-on-rest-api-postmapping/13508/16?u=touna).